# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (don't know what I should do)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Here is the error:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

and it stops here: `con.Open();`

and here is the code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.connection);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    con = com.Connection;
    con.Open();
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText = "select catname,catdescription,photo from category where catid=" + catselectddl.SelectedValue ;
     SqlDataReader dr= com.ExecuteReader();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Load(dr);
     DataRow drr;
     drr=dt.Rows[0];
     con.Close();
```

the error:

```
Line 19:         SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
Line 20:         con = com.Connection;
Line 21:         con.Open(); // here the error
Line 22:         com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
Line 23:         com.CommandText = "select catname,catdescription,photo from category where catid=" + catselectddl.SelectedValue
```

Comment: Make sure your query returns any results

Comment: it is returns results i am sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third line is wrong. It should be

```
  com.Connection = con;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this line (`com.Connection` is `null` at that point):

```
con = com.Connection;
```

to this:

```
com.Connection = con;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the connection in the wrong order.  You should be assigning the connection you create on the first line to the SqlCommand, not assigning the connection of the SqlCommand (which hasn't been created yet) to the SqlConnection variable con you created earlier.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.connection);
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
com.Connection = con
```

You should also check your connection state to make sure it opened successfully before executing your command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.connection);
SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
con.Open();
com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
com.CommandText = "select catname,catdescription,photo from category where catid=" + catselectddl.SelectedValue ;
 SqlDataReader dr= com.ExecuteReader();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Load(dr);
 DataRow drr;
 drr=dt.Rows[0];
 con.Close();
```

You were actually trying to create a connection from a command - the command needs to be assigned a connection, not vice versa.

I would also suggest the "using" syntax which I like, that also takes care of disposal for the command and the connection.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.connection))
{
  using(SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand())
  {
   con.Open();
   com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   com.CommandText = "select catname,catdescription,photo from category where catid=" + catselectddl.SelectedValue ;
   SqlDataReader dr= com.ExecuteReader();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Load(dr);
   DataRow drr;
   drr=dt.Rows[0];
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

"select catname,catdescription,photo from category where catid=" + catselectddl.SelectedValue

On a side note:
This type of SQL Script, if turned into a habit, WILL open doors to `SQL-Injection`; and I assume no developer likes this type of flaw...